# Calculate $\int_{\gamma}zdz$ by using Cauchy's integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

How can I calculate $$\int_{\gamma}zdz~\text{with }\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C},t\mapsto te^{2\pi i t}$$ by using [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)? The line $\gamma$ isn't even closed. Has anyone a hint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Since $z$ is an entire function, the value of the integral along any path from $0$ to $1$ independent of the path.

**SPOILER ALERT:**  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution.

> Cauchy's Integral Theorem states that if $f(z)$ is analytic in and on a closed rectifiable contour $C$, then $$\oint_C f(z)\,dz=0$$Now, this is equivalent to stating that the integral from any point $z_1$ to any other point $z_2$ is path independent.  Therefore, for the problem at hand we have from Cauchy's Integral Theorem $$\begin{align}\oint_C z\,dz=\int_\gamma z\,dz+\int_1^0 x\,dx=0\tag 1 \end{align}$$where we have formed $C$ by adding the straight line path along the real axis that connects the end points of $\gamma$.  Then from $(1)$ it is easy to see that $$\int_\gamma z\,dz=\int_0^1 x\,dx=\frac12$$and we are done!

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I did. But since the exercise is 'by using Cauchy's integral formula' I am not sure if this is the right solution. Is there a way to make $\gamma$ closed and use Cachy directly?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And , yes we can and have applied Cauchy's Integral Theorem and not Cauchy's Integral Formula.  To apply the former, we closed the contour by simply connecting the endpoints $0$ and $1$.  Then, $$\oint_C z\,dz=0 \implies \int_\gamma z\,dz+\int_1^0 x\,dx=0 \implies \int_\gamma z\,dz=\int_0^1 x\,dx=\frac12$$

Comment: What do you mean by 'simply connecting the endpoints $0$ and $1$? What curve?

Comment: It doesn't matter which curve we take that connects the endpoints.  So, we may take the straight line path along the real axis.

Comment: Why it doesn't matter which curve we take to connecting the endpoints? :/

Comment: Cauchy's Integral Theorem is the reason.

Comment: Ok, so you really use Cauchy's theorem and not Cauchy's formula? I must use the formula (linked in the OP). It seems senseless complicate.

Comment: Cauchy's Integral Formula does not facilitate here.

Answer (score 2):

I would not know how to use Cauchy in this problem, but you could notice $f(z)=z$ has a primitive function on $\mathbb{C}$, namely $z^2/2$, so the integral is just the endpoints of the path $\gamma$ plugged into the primitive, by the Fundamental theorem of Calculus. So 
$$\int_{\gamma} z dz = \frac{1}{2}.$$